# JavaScript variable from function used outside the function

Tags: javascript, html

The variable declared in the for loop (variable name = sum) simply doesn't work outside the loop. What am I missing? This variable needs to simply sum the total variables from the table. In this example, I left only one row but there will be plenty.

HERE IS THE [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9jmsydhk/).

PROBLEM: There is nothing in the TOTAL row. It is not calculating.

```
<script>
var c1 = 14.94;

function changeq1() {
    var q1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('q1').value);
    var t1 = q1 * c1;
    var total1 = t1.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('ukupno1').innerHTML = total1;

    var sum = total1;
}
</script>
```

**HTML PAGE**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border: 1px solid black;">
<tr style="text-align:center;">
                <td>"Stiromix"</td>
                <td><div id="c1">14.94</div></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="q1" min="0" max="9999" onchange="changeq1();"></td>
                <td><div id="ukupno1">0.00</div></td>
</tr>
</tr>
                <tr style="text-align:center;">
                <td>TOTAL</td><td></td><td></td>
                <td><div id="total"><script>document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=sum</script></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry. I meant function. I edited my question.

Comment: Assuming that **there is** a `for` loop somewhere in your code, and assuming that you're declaring `var sum = total1` **inside** that loop - you need to declare it outside the loop (or simply remove the `var` and make it global).

Comment: In the fiddle the calculation is working. But the row TOTAL is not getting the sum variable.

Comment: @barakmanos nope, not how JS works. Inside a `function`, yes. Inside a `for` loop, no.

Comment: Can somebody close as duplicate ?

Comment: @dystroy — It is only superficially a duplicate, the underlying problem isn't solved by making the variable a global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've declared `sum` **inside** your function, but then this code hidden away at the bottom of your fiddle tries to use it **outside* the function (It has nothing to do with loops; in fact, I don't see any loops in your code):

```
<script>document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=sum</script>
```

That fails because there is no global `sum` variable.

You probably want to put that code **in** your function, rather than in a separate script block unrelated to it. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jmsydhk/3/) That said, it's unclear why you have both `total1` and `sum`, but my guess is that this code is only part-way complete and `total1` will be (in the final version) for just one row, and `sum` will be for all rows. Or something like that.

Comment: Actually that's right. Total1 is for one row, sum is for sum :) And, you made clear to me about this everything I needed. I misspelled for loop (I meant function) but even I did that you taught me how to do this. Thanx